# How to redefine the caption command with optional arguments

Tags: macros, captions, line-spacing, optional-arguments

I'm writing a thesis that has double spacing on by default throughout the document.  However, captions on figures need to be singlepaced.  I can do that like this

```
\normalsize \singlespace \caption{ bla bla bla}
```

where singlespace is defined as:

```
\newcommand{\singlespace}{\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.0}}
```

---

This gets old, so I want to redefine caption, which I did like this:

```
\let\savedCaption=\caption
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\normalsize\singlespace\savedCaption{#1}}
```

This works fine, but sometimes I want to specify the optional tablename
for my list of tables.  So I do this,

```
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][]{\normalsize\singlespace\savedCaption[#2]{#1}}
```

Unfortunately, this will default the table name to be empty.  The behavior I really
want is this:

```
\renewcommand{\caption}[2][#1]{\normalsize\singlespace\savedCaption[#2]{#1}}
```

...but latex complains about that.

Can anyone help me get caption redefined properly?

Answer (score 8):

Lockstep showed already a solution for singlespaced captions in doublespaced text. However, I would like to answer your specific question about redefining `\caption` in a way such that optional arguments are allowed.

```
\let\savedCaption=\caption
\renewcommand*{\caption}[2][\shortcaption]{%
  \def\shortcaption{#2}
  \normalsize\singlespace
  \savedCaption[#1]{#2}}
```

With this code, if no optional argument has been given, `#1` will be `\shortcaption` which is defined later to have the value of `#2`. If an optional argument has been given, this would be used and `\shortcaption` would simply be ignored.

Comment: just a quick note to say that I get a blank line appearing in the output if I don't have some more comments inside this macro to eat the whitespace.  works great otherwise!

Answer (score 5):

Instead of redefining the `\caption` macro in order to use a custom `\singlespace` macro, I would use the [setspace](http://ctan.org/pkg/setspace) package. It combines double-spacing for  "normal" text with single-spacing for captions.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[doublespacing]{setspace}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\blindtext

\begin{figure}[!ht]
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}
\caption{\blindtext}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

(The [blindtext](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/blindtext/) package is only used to add some dummy text to the example.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use also the [Caption package](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf), which gives you many options to customize the captions of floating environments.

Just as an example, I used in my thesis the following command in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[small,labelfont=bf,hang]{caption}
```

which made all the captions to be printed with a smaller font than the document, with bold font, and with the `hang` option I indented them so that they hang after the first line of text.