# Prepend text to Caption

Tags: captions

Captions are set up like `Figure 1. Caption`, I need it to be `Figure 1. <text> Caption`, with the same text to all figures, and I need it to be part of the caption, not figure name **.

I tried with what I know and did

```
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{ \caption{<text> #1} }
```

And that didn't work because all the captions in my text are written as `\caption[shortcaption]{caption}`. Found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/17504/how-to-redefine-the-caption-command-with-optional-arguments) which was really insightful, but I couldn't make it work with changes I thought of doing.

Clearly, I need to define caption correctly by including `\shortcaption` in the redefinition but I don't know how to do that.

How do I prepend text to caption as explained above? Thanks!

---

** This is a workaround I found for another problem. In book class, using a template I didn't write and can't change for my thesis, captions are not justified even with the correct package settings. But they do justify if before writing the caption I add the code `\vspace{0pt}\justifying\noindent`. So, I want to prepend that to my caption command and avoid writing it every time.

Comment: Your redefinition creates a circular referencing of `\caption` which will trigger an infinite loop.  Using `\Caption` instead, newly defined as `\newcommand{\Caption}[1]{ \caption{<text> #1} }` could be a way out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution is to use the caption package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionFormat{silly}{#1#2<text> #3}
\captionsetup{format=silly,labelsep=period}
\usepackage{blindtext}% MWE only
\begin{document}
\listoffigures

\begin{figure}[htp]
\caption[short caption]{\blindtext}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]